# Is there any use for the beta Bloodstones?

Tags: dota-2

Some said that the item is given to those who participate in DOTA 2 Beta.

**There are 3 kind of blood stones**

### Tier 1 - Bloodstone of the Ancestor (Rare)

[image]

### Tier 2 - Bloodstone of the Precursor (Mythical)

[image]

### Tier 3 - Bloodstone of the Founder (Legendary)

[image]

Now, it is the official release of Dota 2, what are the uses of it?

Is there any future uses of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now, no, there is use for any of the Bloodstones. They're merely there to show off to people that you were a part of the beta and how generous you were with your beta invites. As for whether or not there will be a use for them, we obviously have no idea, but I would guess that there isn't going to be.

Comment: That's sad, but there's something to brag about to the new players.

Answer (score 0):

Although useless so far, they do make a good choice for the "featured items" showcase in your profile, since it at least has a chance of being seen there.

Answer (score 0):

You would've gotten `Bloodstone of the Ancestor` if you only participated and did not send out any gifts/invites,
the `Bloodstone of the Precursor` if you sent out 1 or more and if you had sent out more than 10 you would've received `Bloodstone of the Founder`

They only display the amount of invites you sent out.  As Ullallulloo said there will most likely be no use for them.